# Solr group by multiple fields

Tags: solr, group-by

Does Solr allowing grouping by multiple field much like in SQL with GROUP BY?

If so how?

For example: If I wanted to group by name and email. I have tried adding multiple group fields...

`group=true&group.field=name&group.field=email`

But it only groups by one of the fields.

I have looked at other posts with similar questions, but none had a verified answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you cannot have intersection between grouped results at **query time** based on group.field.

The remaining solution would be to create the combination of the two fields into a new one at **index time** and use that new field for grouping which would give you the results.

See : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html